# How can we generate all submatrix of a given 2D matrix in java or C++?

Tags: java, c++, algorithm

I am using this loop structure but it fails to generate all the submatrix that are possible for any given 2D matrix with n rows and m columns.

```
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<m;j++)
        {
            System.out.println("sub-MATRIX:");
            for(k=i;k<n;k++)
            {
                for(p=j;p<m;p++)
                {
                   System.out.print(arr[k][p]+" ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
```

Ex: Given matrix 3X3 : [[1 2 3],[4 5 6],[7 8 9]]
Then its submatrix will be:
for size 1:
[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9]
for size 4:
[[1,2],[4,5]],[[2,3],[5,6]],[[4,5],[7,8]] and [[5,6],[8,9]]
and so on

Comment: Please provide some more details: what is the input, expected output, actual output?

Comment: Sub-Matrix of which size?

Comment: How is this related to C++? Also it sounds more like an algorithm problem

Comment: @K.Kirsz I have added an example. Task is to generate all submatrix possible of all sizes in a given matrix

Comment: Think of it this way : you are looking for all possible top-left corners of a UxV matrix inside a MxN matrix. There are (M-U+1) x (N-V+1) candidates. Simply iterate over these.

Comment: @UnholySheep stack overflow already has a solution to this problem but it is in python and uses some inbuilt functions which are not available in java or C++

Comment: @fzd task is to display all submatrices which I am unable to do.It will be really helpful if you can give the algo or pseudocode

Comment: @mohdanishh Please don't post questions related to ongoing contest problems.

Comment: is there any efficient approach to find sum of each possible submatrix in a matrix?

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a couple more loops to cover all cases.  `PrintMatyrix()` should have 2 nested loops for printing contents.

```
  for (i = 1; i < n; ++i)
  {
    for (j = 1; j < m; ++j)
    {
      // we are at each sub matrix of size(i,j)
      for (k = 0; k <= (n - i); ++k)
      {
        for (p = 0; p <= (m - j); ++p)
        {
           // we are at submatrix of size(i,j) starting at (k,p)
           // assuming PrintMatrix(Matrix&, int rows, int cols, int r0, int c0);   
           PrintMatrix(arr, i, j, k, p);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

If we have a matrix with dimensions M x N, and the sub matrix we are looking for is with K x L dimensions. If there is more optimized solution, please share.

```
for (int i = 0; i < m-k+1; i++) {   
                for (int j = 0; j < n-l+1; j++) {
                    for (int p = 0; p < k; p++) {
                        for(int q = 0; q < l; q++) {
                            System.out.print(arr[i+p][j+q] + " ");
                        }
                        System.out.println();
                    }
                    System.out.println("*****************");

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not loops, you should use some recursions.

Think about this way, for each row or column, you either take it or throw away it. So you can select rows first and then columns and based on the rows and columns selected you construct the submatrix.

Some code,

```
bool rowTaken[N], columnTaken[M];
void constructSubMatrixRow(int i)
{
    if (i >= N) constructSubMatrixCol(0);
    rowTaken[i] = true;
    constructSubMatrix(i+1);
    rowTaken[i] = false;
    constructSubMatrix(i+1);
}

void constructSubMatrixCol(int i)
{
    if (i >= M) printSubMatrix();
    columnTaken[i] = true;
    constructSubMatrixCol(i+1);
    columnTaken[i] = false;
    constructSubMatrixCol(i+1);
}

void printSubMatrix()
{
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < N; i++)
        if (rowTaken[i]){
            for (unsigned j = 0; j < M; j++)
               if (columnTaken[j])
                  print matrix[i][j]
        }
}
```

Comment: what are the row and column bounds for the function printSubMatrix() ?

Comment: @mohdanishh, printSubMatrix is just to print out the submatrix constructed using rowTaken and columnTaken. See the updated pseudo code

Comment: it will be really helpful if you can construct the function  
printSubMatrix() , it will help me understand your algorithms completely.Thanks

Comment: @mohdanishh, please refresh and see the updated code